# UITableView not populating in Tab bar iPhone application

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidload

I have a tab bar application which loads a UITableView when one of it's buttons are selected. It seems to load the view controller however it doesn't seem to be populating the data. I have tried setting the cell.text = @"cell" (while setting the number of rows > 0) and an NSLog in the CellForRowAtIndexPath proves that in fact the function is not being called. The same NSLog output to the console in the viewDidLoad function also generates no output so it seems as though its not getting called.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try and call [tableView reloadData] from your -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; method. This should be called each time the user navigates to that tab and should set off the delegate callbacks that aren't currently being called. If they still aren't called make sure you have set the table delegate to self.

EDIT: Actually make sure you have set your table view's delegate and datasource to self;